# Updating library version, but transitive dependenies stay the same

Tags: spring, maven, reactor-netty

In order to fix [CVE-2022-41881](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-41881) I want to update the dependency for netty under `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.7.1` from version `1.0.20` to `1.1.1`

This is the section of the dependency tree before the change:

```
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
```

When forcing the use of a newer dependency for `reactor-netty-http` like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I end up with this dependency tree:

```
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.78.Final:compile
```

As you can see the `reactor-netty-http` has the correct version, but all the dependencies underneath are still in the same version also according to [Maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor.netty/reactor-netty-http/1.1.1) they should have `4.1.86.Final`

These dependencies are only defined through `reactor-netty-http`, so there should not be anything else that forces it to a lower version.

Any idea why an outdated version is used here?

Comment: The most important thing I see here that you are using an older version of spring boot (2.7.1) why not upgrading to the most recent one (2.7.6) which very likely will contain an updated version of netty as well..

Comment: @khmarbaise Updating the spring boot dependencies (even updating `spring-boot-starter-webflux` which is the parent or `reactor-netty-http` does not resolve the issue and also does not fix the vulnerability as the spring boot side of things use an older version.

Comment: Then you should go with the solution described by Violeta Georgieva

Comment: Are you using the spring boot parent as the parent of your project or do you use the spring-boot-dependencies in your project via scope import?

Answer (score 1):

The Netty version is controlled by Spring Boot. In order to update it, in your `pom.xml` add the property below

```
<properties>
    <netty.version>4.1.86.Final</netty.version>
</properties>
```

See more [here](https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/Cairo-SR7/reference/html/getting-started-overriding-versions.html)

Comment: I was not aware of this property. Does not fix the problem. I assume that the issue might be that my netty problem comes from `spring-boot-starter-webflux` which is not directly part of the spring-boot bom. There is also another bom abstraction between my app and Spring boot. To me it looks like the versions use a hard coded value somewhere and do not use the property

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `spring-boot-dependencies` via import scope (BOM) in your project instead of the `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent of your project. You have to beware of the following that you have to define the `netty-bom` before the `spring-boot-dependencies` bom in your `dependencyManagement`.

The following will overwrite the versions of the netty parts correctly:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
       ...
       <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.86.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Now I see my problem. The `spring-boot-dependencies` is defined in the parent pom that I import. Is there a way to handle this indirection, because just defining it as mentioned above in my dependencyManagement does not have the desired effect.

Comment: `is defined in the parent pom that I import.` ? Are you using a different parent than spring-boot...it's becoming hard to understand post your pom file...Do you use scope import or have you defined it as a dependency instead???

Comment: Bad wording on my part: What I wanted to express was the dependencies are managed through importing of `bom`s and that there is an intermediary bom between my application and and spring. In effect the intermediary imports `spring-boot-dependencies` without the `netty-bom`. Therefor it is my understanding that declaring both of them on my level does not work.

Comment: Can you make an example project on github or alike to have a real project to talk about...